# while condition for find function of hash map c++

Tags: c++

I am taking a course implementing linear probing of hash map and this is the part where the lecturer implemented a function _find() that fetches the index of the target value,which is pos.key here, from the hash table.

But as I'm reading the code I came to doubt whether the while loop's condition is correct because I'm not sure whether the index and start variables are initialized as the head index of the hash table.

I mean, if the search starts from the middle of the hash table and it meets a node with status EMPTY in its searching, as it is linear probing, it would return false without either continuing the search, even though that was just an empty node between available or deleted nodes, or searching the former part to the start point where could still be values left yet to be searched.

For example, if the given hash table is like below and the search started from the fourth node [avail],

[avail][deleted][avail][avail][deleted][empty][avail]

wouldn't it be possible that it would end searching when it meets [empty] without looking at all nodes?

Or would've the lecturer assumed that hash() of m_hash is defined to initialize the index and the start variables as the head index of the hash table?

I'm asking here to check whether my doubt is reasonable. Thank you for reading my question and any advice would be appreciated.

```
template<class TYPE, class HASH>
bool HashMap<TYPE,HASH>::_find(MapPos& pos) const
{
    int start, index;
    index = start = m_hash.hash(pos.key) % m_nArraySize;
    while(m_pArray[index].status != EMPTY) // AVAIL or DELETED
    {
        if(m_pArray[index].status == AVAIL && m_pArray[index].data==pos.key)
        {
            pos.index = index;
            return true;
        } 
        index= (index+ _next(pos.key)) % m_nArraySize;//_next() returns 1 making it linear probing
        if(index==start) return false;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: It might have been useful to specify clearly what behaviour you expect from this function. Hash Maps are a common concept, but from the concept to the implementation there is always a lot of freedom.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> if the search starts from the middle of the hash table and it meets a
>   node with status EMPTY in its searching, as it is linear probing, it
>   would return false without either continuing the search

What makes you think that the function will return false when an EMPTY node is found ? The condition

```
if(index==start) return false;
```

ensures that false can only be returned after the whole range of index has been probed. Lok at this instruction in the loop:

```
index= (index+ _next(pos.key)) % m_nArraySize;
```

When `index` reaches `m_nArraySize`, the modulo `%` will make it become 0, and the search will continue at the beginning of the array. As a result, the start index can be anywhere on the array.

Comment: even if it doesn't satisfy index==start, if the status is empty it breaks the while loop and returns false

Comment: You're right, there should be a ``return true`` at the end.

Comment: Actually it depends of what behaviour you expect when meeting an empty node. Should the key be written ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hash map returns a "not found" result without looking at all of the entries. That's rather the *point* of having a data-structure more complex than a raw array.

That's why there is a `DELETED` status. If you remove an entry, anything located after it still has to be findable, under the rule that encountering `EMPTY` when searching forward indicates that the tested-for value isn't in the map.

A good hash function will evenly distribute keys throughout the array, so that the likelihood is that you will encounter either the key being searched for, or `EMPTY`, in the first spot searched, and return immediately. Doing lots of linear probing is a sign of a bad hash (or malevolent input)

Comment: @HJY no, that's an example of the key not being present. There's only ever one place a key can go for a given state.

Comment: @HJY if an entry with that key exists in the map, you find it by the described method, and find returns true. If there is not an entry with that key, you get an index for where it *must* go